# CMake: How to link against a static 3rd party lib?

Tags: build, linker, build-process, cmake

What I have: my code (simple main.cpp), headers of the 3rd party lib (EnvVar `TPLIB_INCLUDE`), binary lib (several .a files in `TPLIB_BINARY_PATH`) and the following CMakeLists.txt:

```
# current source directory: CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR
# current binary directory: CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR

# require 2.6 to get support for the simple IF construct
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.6.0)

PROJECT( simpleapp)
SET( PROGNAME simpleapp )

SET( CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE ON )
SET( CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON )
SET( CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR TRUE )

# the actual .cpp files go here
SET(project_SOURCES
    main.cpp
)

# add here all files that need processing by Qt's MOC if there are any
set(project_MOC_SOURCES
    # files would go here
)

# add here all files that will be processed by Qt's UIC
set(project_UIS
    # all .ui files would go here
)

# additional Qt resources go here
set(project_RCCS
    # all .qrc files would go here
)

# setup Qt
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt4 REQUIRED)

INCLUDE(${QT_USE_FILE})

QT4_WRAP_CPP(test_MOCS ${project_MOC_SOURCES})
QT4_WRAP_UI(test_UIS_H ${project_UIS})
QT4_WRAP_CPP(test_MOC_UI ${project_UIS_H})
QT4_ADD_RESOURCES(test_RCC_SRCS ${project_RCCS})

include_directories( ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} $ENV{TPLIB_INCLUDE})

ADD_EXECUTABLE( ${PROGNAME} ${project_SOURCES} ${test_MOCS} ${test_RCC_SRCS} ${test_MOC_UI} )

link_directories($ENV{TPLIB_BINARY_PATH})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROGNAME} ${QT_LIBRARIES} lib_misc lib_tools)
```

`make`ing the project creating the `main.cpp.o` works as usual. Thus CMake found the third party headers. When it comes to link `ld` complains cannot find -llib_misc and -llib_tools. 
Removing the "link_directories" line or specifiingy the libs absolute name leads to "No rule to make target /path/to/lib_misc.a"

So how to tell CMake to use these libs for linking only?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`link_directories($ENV{TPLIB_BINARY_PATH})` should be placed before `ADD_EXECUTABLE`.

From [the official documents of CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:link_directories), there are notes on `link_directories`:

> The command will apply only to targets created after it is called.

Comment: Alternatively, avoid using link_directories altogether, and use the full path names of the library files in the target_link_libraries argument list: "target_link_libraries(${PROGNAME} ${QT_LIBRARIES} $ENV{TPLIB_BINARY_PATH}/liblib_misc.a $ENV{TPLIB_BINARY_PATH}/liblib_tools.a)" If the file name is actually "lib_misc.a" then you only need to pass "_misc" to target_link_libraries if you are using link_directories before add_executable...

Comment: What do you mean by "This"? Using full path names, or using the short name? Both should definitely work with CMake 2.8.9. If not, you have a typo or there's a bug... Specific steps to repro the problem should be mentioned on the CMake mailing list. People there can help you find the typo or get it fixed.